# zed attack proxy tool eroor : JVM_bind

Tags: security, testing, jvm, zap

I have configured my google chroome browser with **ZAP** default Port "8080" and "LocalHost" as found google . 
and while entering any http request it says Look proxy settings
    Already in use: JVM_Bind
[image]

I have checked with the command in system `netstat -an` it shows port `8080` is Listening mode .

Also not able to add to add the certificates to my browser, checked lots of stuffs from google , also tried with reinstalling the software, so Kindly help me with proper solutions .
[image]

- Q1> What is that **JVM_Bind** error while starting .
- Q2> How to start recording in my browser .
- Q3> Is there any option to change the default proxy setting of **ZAP Tool** .
- Q4> How to Install the **Certificates** for
  "https" types request.

Plz understand the issue and proper solution .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That means another process is listening on port 8080.
You could change whatever process that is, but its probably easier to just change ZAP to listen on another port, eg 8090

Comment: Psiinon , I wrote that on my post but how to change **ZAP Default Port** number. Please help with that.

Comment: In the ZAP UI select Tools / Options... / Local Proxy and then change the port.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the JVM_bind problem and later solved the issue. so the ans of your following question

Q2> How to start recording in my browser

Q3> Is there any option to change the default proxy setting of ZAP Tool is

```
1. Launch OWASP ZAP
2. Navigate to Tools>> Options>> Local Proxy
3. Change the port number (default 8080) >> make it something else like 8888[make sure other application is not using 8888 port]
4. Restart zap.
5. Configure the firefox Manual proxy configuration: as 8888 
6. Browse the application you want to perform security test
```

Hope the above configuration will solve your problem.